# Wordpress Responsive Image ( srcset ) not work properly

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, responsive

I have a very strange problem

There are images with the correct size on the host and image sizes are properly recorded in WordPress

But I get the following html code output

```
<img width="300" height="200" src="https://site.site/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Imagename.jpg" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="https://site.site/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Imagename.jpg" class="attachment-us_300_200 size-us_300_200 wp-post-image lazy-loaded" alt="IMAGETITLE" srcset="" data-srcset="https://site.site/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Imagename.jpg 400w, https://site.site/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Imagename.jpg 600w, https://site.site/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Imagename.jpg 300w, https://site.site/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Imagename.jpg 900w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" title="IMAGETITLE">
```

The size I requested was 300x200 pixels
but, the image is displayed in full size and the loading speed of the site is greatly reduced.

This problem occurred a week ago after a few plugin and theme updates

- Disabled all plugins and theme > noting changed
- Manual replacement wordpress files > noting changed
- Change the PHP version > noting changed

Sorry for the bad English
Can anyone help me?

Comment: `srcset` is used by the _browser_ to decide which image to load. WordPress isn't choosing which to use.

Comment: i khow that . the problem is wordpress not add image size for main image and srcet . wordpress sould add size in file adress like : imagename-200x300.jpg
but my wordpress not doing that.